# Not able to hide the div

Tags: c#, html

I'm not able to hide the in code. I have given `Id` to div also I have given runat server property to it but on running the code Div is visible . Please help.
My code is like this :

```
<a href="RoomTypeView.aspx">
                <div class="dash-thum-bg" id="rt" runat="server">
                    <img src="../App_Themes/Akeel/images/thumb-1.gif" />
                    <span>Room Type</span>
                </div>
```

In code I am writing

```
rt.visible=false
```

Comment: Where in your code are you writing?

Comment: rt.attributes.Add('display','none') try something like this. or CssAttributes, Css...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your div around a panel. Then u can hide the panel in the code behind.

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" id="divtohide">
<a href="RoomTypeView.aspx">
            <div class="dash-thum-bg" id="rt" runat="server">
                <img src="../App_Themes/Akeel/images/thumb-1.gif" />
                <span>Room Type</span>
            </div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

code behind

```
divtohide.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript -

```
function hideMyDiv()
{
    document.getElementById('rt').style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Add a style -

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

Now call it by codebehind